# Javascript only works partially

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a script that will remove a class on two li items after click and add a class to another li item. I have used the .className method but it only works partially.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="tbh lista">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="tbh lista">
            <a href="#"><img src="images/mail.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="lista">
            <a href="#" onclick="changeClass()" id="phone"><img     src="images/phone.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="lista hidden">
            <p>text</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the script:

```
function changeClass(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('tbh');
    for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i <=len; i++) {
        elements[i].className='hidden';

        console.log('aaa');
    }
}
```

After I click the li item once, only one of the li items disappears and I get an error. I have to click it twice for it to function properly. I can't find the error.
These are displayed in console.log: `aaa
                                     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined`

Comment: `<=` seems to be the culprit.

Comment: I have modified it to < and still, the same eror.

Comment: add comsole.log(i) and see which element is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `document.getElementsByClassName` returns HTMLCollection but not Array. So change your string

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('tbh');
```

to

```
var elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('tbh'));
```